# SMTP verification without using PHPMailer or PEAR

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp

I'm currently working on a schoolproject, where we have to create a big website with all sorts of functionality, but we cannot use any kind of library, i was wondering how i could apply a SMTP verification using with tls without the use of PEAR or any thing like it, i have currently been trying to send mail using this class

https://hastebin.com/ogukitalip.php

but this is to no avail, i'm trying to create my own settings to authenticate it somehow.

I tested it this way:

```
<?php

include_once 'private/objects/mailer/mail-handler-class.php';

$mailer = mail_handler::get_instance();

$mailer->set_message("<b>This is a message</b>");
$mailer->set_subject("A test message!");

$mailer->is_html();
$mailer->is_smtp();

$mailer->set_smtp_host("********");
$mailer->set_smtp_port(587); #the port

$mailer->set_smtp_auth_username("*******"); #smtp authentication username
$mailer->set_smtp_auth_password("**********"); #smtp authentication password

$mailer->set_sender("test@********.nl"); #sender
$mailer->set_receiver("********@gmail.com"); #receiver

if(!$mailer->send_mail()) {
    echo "failed";
} else {
    echo "sent!";
}
```

Comment: what is your hosting provider?

Comment: @SumanDey i'm using transip

Comment: I think you use normal php email script. If you use smtp then go to php mailer

Comment: @SumanDey I cannot use phpmailer, we cannot use any libraries

Comment: Ok you use normal mailer then its not require any libraries  or smtp. Cpanel send 500 mail in hour free. You can use this.

Comment: @SumanDey it does say that it cannot connect to the SMTP even if i'm not trying to use it, that's why i thought it is mandatory

Comment: OK you use normaly mail.

Comment: It easy. if you don't know how add this then go to my profile fb.com/dxvil  i send an attachment you understand then